# Can a cloned page have HTTPS certificates?

Tags: tls, http

Imagine that a hacker is cloning Twitter or Facebook. The attacker uses his own website, but it is going to be HTTP, right? So can he have the certificates that ensure that his website is "secure" showing the green confirmation before the url in the browser?

Comment: HTTPS is not about *pages* or *content*, it's about *server*. It only ensures you're talking to the server *you intended to*, but otherwise in no way guarantees that the content is not fraudulent or in any form.

Comment: @iBug Or as [my favorite explanation](https://twitter.com/shanselman/status/187572289724887041) puts it, "HTTPS & SSL doesn't mean 'trust this.' It means 'this is private.' You may be having a private conversation with Satan."

Answer (score 41):

> ...  have the certificates that ensure that his website is "secure" showing the green confirmation before the url in the browser?

It is still a common misconception that certificates **ensure** that a website is "secure".

Certificates and use of HTTPS **do not say anything about the inherent security of a website**. What they do instead is to **protect the communication** between the client (browser) and the server (website) against sniffing or manipulation by an attacker. Use of certificates also makes sure that the website displayed is actually the one which is **shown in the URL bar**.

But it does not make sure that that it is actually the site you **believe** it is or the site you've **intended** to visit. It does not protect against cloned sites or look-alike sites or similar looking domain names. Certificate issuers (CA) don't control what content is served on the domain, i.e. it is easy to get a certificate for sites serving malware, look-alike sites asking for your password (i.e. credential phishing) etc.

Certificates and HTTPS protect against **insecure networks**, like open WiFi hotspots or malicious internet providers. They **don't protect against malicious websites** though.

Comment: Just wanted to add regarding the verbiage "*still a common misconception*" that Google Chrome actually tells users that a website is "Not Secure" when it is not served over HTTPS. I'm not arguing that Chrome is wrong for saying it this way... certainly some intelligent people put a lot of thought into the choice of that wording. It's hard to strike a balance between educating and over complicating.

Comment: @AaronCicali I think you consider that out of its context. Not secure means that the middle man can intercept the communication on HTTP, nothing more. Secure means that the connection is HTTPS and the certificate is valid, nothing more. It doesn't say the website is non-malicious. Facebook? Maybe you are using already MITM'ed HTTPS due to your company, etc...

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks! I understand what it means, in context. I just wanted to clarify when I read "*It is **still** a common misconception*" that in time the confusion will only grow. The world's most popular browser conflates the two - showing that a website with an HTTPS certificate is *secure*, but a website without an HTTPS certificate is *insecure*. No judgement on my part though... it's probably better to conflate these concepts than to encourage unencrypted traffic or try to truly educate the average user.

Comment: @AaronCicali: Stating a short *"Not secure"* when using  HTTP does not imply "Secure" when it is not there. And a short "Not secure" is also correct - if the connection is not secure you don't know if you really have the expected content. The details then also point out where the insecurity comes from. Browser had shown in the past a "Secure" sign but modified their behavior in order to fight the misconception that HTTPS means secure.  Currently Chrome just shows a lock and says *"__Connection__ is secure"* when using HTTPS.

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't depend on the page being cloned, but what the domain is. Copying the page is simple and anyone can do it. But they cannot clone the domain.

So, they either try to register a domain that is close to the thing they want to copy, like `twltter.com` or, they don't bother being clever and register a random string as a domain, like `jjc899deedh.com` (yes, this works). Then they simply get a TLS certificate for that domain and get the green confirmation icon.

Or they could hack a legitimate site and host the cloned pages on the hacked site (`frankshardwarestore.com/files/twitter.com`). By doing this, they don't need to register a domain or get a certificate because they use the hacked site's certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Things you can do to serve a hacked clone of, say, twitter to your victim:

- Make them use your DNS server instead of the correct one (relatively easy for a dedicated attack; might be easier if you are their ISP or evil sysadmin) and resolve twitter.com to your own ip instead of the original. Let's ignore any problems you might get with signed DNS
- Serve your malicious clone over http and hope that the victim is fine with that. This won't work because HSTS headers told the victim in their last visit that they should expect https. Even if they never visited twitter before, this domain is certainly among the preloaded HSTS sites known to the browser beforehand
- So your clone better serve https. You will have difficulties obtaining a generally accepted certificate for your private key (but if you are a rogue nation and have control over a generally accepted CA, you can go ahead).
- So you perhaps try your own, perhaps even self-signed certificate? The victim browser may reject that right away, or give a serious warning to the user. In the latter case, you may be lucky and perhaps the victim is one of those many users who shrug and click warnings away. Note however, that the original site may have published information that only certain CAs can issue their certificates, so if the victim browser checks such info, you still lose. Then again, this info is in DNS, which you already have under your control, see above, yay!
- Alternatively, try to use the original certificate of twitter.com. This requires the use of their original private key. This is called private for a reason, i.e., you'd have to completely own their server to extract (either by hacking into it until yo have root access, or perhaps it is easier to take literal ownership by buying the company).
- Given the difficulties listed above, it may be easier to convince your victim into a browser of your choice (and of your making) that deliberately ignores all the security mechanisms listed above. It might even be hardcoded to serve twiter.com from your ip without checking DNS, and even display a green bar for your captured site when it doesn't even serve https. This seems a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

There are already sufficient answers, but I wanted to give you a quick guide to try this yourself, or at least see how trivial it is.

Use a domain you have registered, or find somewhere you can point a subdomain for free to your server, or whatever - get a domain you can use.

Spin up a free instance on AWS Lightsail, either lamp, nginx, or Wordpress (most other pre-configured options will work too)

copy and paste the IP address to the A record of your domain (wait ~10 min, if you set DNS settings correctly)

click 'login via ssh' and when the browser-terminal pops up type: sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool

Follow the prompts and in a couple minutes you have a fully activated, with http->https redirecting web server using a certificate from the most widely trusted certificate authority in the world.

This is just one of many extremely easy ways to configure a valid ssl certificate. 'Let's Encrypt' makes it sooo easy for anyone to get a valid ssl cert, even if you're just on your own hardware with a web server installed - might take 5 minutes longer. My point is, you can do this yourself for a non-existent/pointless site in a few minutes. - ANYONE can get a little padlock icon by their website. As others have mentioned, it doesn't mean anything in terms of reputability of the site, or imply it serves a legitimate purpose in anyway. It simply encrypts the traffic and validates the URL and the server 'match'. Relying on it for anything else is asking for trouble.

P.S. the ease of generating and using SSL certs is 100% a boon - yes it makes it easier for malicious actors to get one, but encrypting web traffic is the goal of the technology, not preventing user visits to malicious websites - and the more of the web that's encrypted, the better. Didn't want to convey the opposite by mentioning how easy it is for malicious actors to acquire one

Comment: Or even easier, just put a scraped page onto GitHub Pages and see how `username.github.io` is secure.

Comment: @iBug I wanted to show it on 'your own' domain, but good call - that's a great, simple proof of concept.